# Jquery select dropdown - insert into hidden form field

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the selected value of my Jquery select dropdown into a hidden form field. I've got as far as fetching the selected value, but it just sets the hidden value to OBJECT OBJECT.

Do I need to convert it to a string or something first ?

I'm using this plugin: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

And this is my code:

```
var ddBasic = [
  { text: "House", value: "house", },
  { text: "Condominium", value: "condo", },
  { text: "Office", value: "office", }
];

$('#propertytype').ddslick({
  data: ddBasic,
  selectText: "Select a property type",
  showSelectedHTML : false,
  onSelected: function(selectedData){
    $("#property_type").val(selectedData);
  } 
});

var ddBasic2 = [
  { text: "Rent", value: "rent", },
  { text: "Buy", value: "buy", }
];

$('#acquiring').ddslick({
  data: ddBasic2,
  selectText: "Do you want to buy or rent ?",
  showSelectedHTML : false,
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
    $("#acquire_type").val(selectedData);
  } 
});
```

Comment: Ok just figured it out:  

`onSelected: function(data){          $("#property_type").val(data.selectedData.value);`

Comment: You can answer your own question in the "Your Answer" box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting selectedData as a object. You need to fetch the value from it by

```
selectedData.selectedData.value
```

So making it more simple, this is how your code should look

```
var ddBasic = [
  { text: "House", value: "house", },
  { text: "Condominium", value: "condo", },
  { text: "Office", value: "office", }
];

$('#propertytype').ddslick({
  data: ddBasic,
  selectText: "Select a property type",
  showSelectedHTML : false,
  onSelected: function(selectedObj){
    $("#property_type").val(selectedObj.selectedData.value);
  } 
});

var ddBasic2 = [
  { text: "Rent", value: "rent", },
  { text: "Buy", value: "buy", }
];

$('#acquiring').ddslick({
  data: ddBasic2,
  selectText: "Do you want to buy or rent ?",
  showSelectedHTML : false,
    onSelected: function(selectedObj){
    $("#acquire_type").val(selectedObj.selectedData.value);
  } 
});
```

Check the point number 5 on the plugin site http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick